# Import OSM all tags using osm2pgrouting

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap

How to use terminal to import downloaded .osm data with all the "tags" into postgresql db.

I am using this for now:

```
osm2pgrouting -file /home/zia/Documents/Test/konya.osm -conf /usr/share/osm2pgrouting/mapconfig.xml -host localhost -port 5432 -dbname osm_dem -user postgres -passwd zia123 -prefixtables kn_ -clean
```

Comment: Where are you stuck? Does the command in your question work? Does it fail? Is the result not the one you are expecting?

Comment: Using the above code, I can easily import the osm data into my Db. But in my "ways" table in the PostGIS Db, I have only few osm tags like "name", "maxspeed", "osm_id", plus some additional columns been generated by the osm2pgrouting function. But checking the .osm xml file, we can see that there are so many other tags also attached with the ways or nodes. How to import all those tags also into my "ways" table using osm2pgrouting? Mainly I want "oneway" tag additional.

Comment: Following is the small section of my .osm data file and you can see that there are other tags also attached with the edge, but I don't know how to import those also?

<tag k="highway" v="residential"/>
<tag k="name" v="Prof. Sıddık Sami Onar Caddesi"/>
<tag k="oneway" v="yes"/>